# How do I save a choice of member variable in C#?

Tags: c#, reference

I am using a class with the following member variables

```
class SomeClass
{
    int    idx0_value;
    int    idx1_value;
    int    idx2_value;

    //...
}
```

I'm not able to change the structure of this class.

I am using an instance of this class to check against a previously selected index and assigning a corresponding value to a variable using some `if-else` statements :

```
if(indexIFoundEarlier == 0)
    valueIWant = aSomeClass.idx0_value;
else if(indexIFoundEarlier == 1)
    valueIWant = aSomeClass.idx1_value;
else
    valueIWant = aSomeClass.idx2_value;
```

This seems fairly inefficient.

In C++ I could effectively store a reference to the relevant member, but in C# this isn't possible, I've read the various threads on this.

Is there a better (read more efficient) way of caching the choice I've made without changing the structure of "SomeClass"?

Comment: Take a look at the decorator design pattern.

Comment: If efficiency isn't much of a concern, you could always use reflection.

Comment: There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow discussing selecting and accessing object members programmatically at runtime. In your specific example, using reflection or making a dictionary of accessor delegates might be appropriate, but it's impossible to know with such a vaguely worded question. Please provide a good [mcve] that clearly shows your scenario, explain what specific techniques you've already researched, and what specifically you've had trouble with in implementing one or more of these techniques.

Comment: Not being facetious - aren't you in effect "caching the choice" by storing it in `valueIWant`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate...

```
class SomeClass {

   int idx0_value;
   int idx1_value;
   int idx2_value;

   private Func<int> selection;

   private void SetSelection( int choice ) {
      switch( choice ) {
      case 0:
         selection = () => idx0_value;
         break;
      case 1:
         selection = () => idx1_value;
         break;
      case 2:
         selection = () => idx2_value;
         break;
      }
   }

   private int GetSelectionAgain() {
      return selection?.Invoke() ?? -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However this seems fairly inefficient. In C++ I could effectively
>   store a reference to the relevant member, but in C# this isn't
>   possible, I've read the various threads on this.

It is not inefficient, using a switch statement would be your only other reasonable choice for this case in my opinion. The overhead of using reflection or any kind of delegation would be way higher than just doing `if-else` statements or a `switch` statement.

```
//same concept as what you posted but as a switch statement
switch( indexIFoundEarlier ) 
{
  case 0:
     valueIWant = idx0_value;
     break;
  case 1:
     valueIWant = idx1_value;
     break;
  default:
     valueIWant  = idx2_value;
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an extension. Is it efficient? That's subjective until its compared to something. But it's readable, and that's important. If your logic is this simple and someone comes along and finds it done in a convoluted way, first they're going to read it several times assuming that they must be missing something. Then when they realize it's doing something simple they might wonder why it wasn't done simply.

That happens all the time when refactoring code. We come across something complex (maybe even something we wrote and forgot) and when we understand it we say to ourselves, "Is that all it does?" and then replace it with something simpler.

```
public static class SomeClassExtensions
{
     public static int GetValueFromIndex(this SomeClass someClass, int index)
     {
         if(index == 0) return someClass.idx0_value;
         if(index == 1) return someClass.idx1_value;
         return someClass.idx2_value;
     }
}

var value = aSomeClass.GetValueFromIndex(indexIFoundEarlier);
```